# Access textbox.text from one class to another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add `textbox9.Text` from `Form1` to the filename that is in another class. I've made it public, but it doesn't work. Thanks

I need the data from this:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox9;
```

to be in the filename of the new document:

```
object newFileName = Path.Combine(_fileInfo.DirectoryName, "docs", _fileInfo.Name + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy"));
```

Comment: Always add _relevant_ code as text. Don't link to it or post images of it.

Comment: A [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would contain more info than 2 lines of code, and also easier to read than the (originally posted) 818 lines of code.

Comment: making the entire control public is never a good idea you can simply pass the ```Text``` to another class to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing through a bunch of dictionary KeyPairValues, so you could grab it from there (assuming the key $13 will always have the value of textBox9, its hardcoded in the form so until that changes this should be valid).

```
var newFileName = Path.Combine(_fileInfo.DirectoryName, "docs", _fileInfo.Name + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy"));

if (items.ContainsKey("$13"))
{
    var textBox9Value = items["$13"];
    newFileName = $"{newFileName}_{textBox9Value}";
}
```